# How do you label axes when using i and j?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

When I use $x$ and $y$ axes I would put an arrow at the end of the axes with a little $+x$ or $+y$.

But when dealing with vectors I'm not sure how to label them.

I'm thinking either: $+\hat{i}$, $+\vec{i}$ or just $+i$.

Which of these should be used to label the $i$ vector axis?

Comment: In case of two dimensions, label them with 1 and 2, where 1 (2) refers to the first (second) coordinate of your vector representation.

Answer (score 0):

$i$ just means a unitary vector in some predefined direction, you have the freedom to label that vector as you wish. Here are some common notations

- $\hat{x}$
- $\hat{e}_x$
- $\hat{e}_1$
- $\hat{x}_1$
- (...)

Perhaps the first one is more intuitive if you wish to add it to a frame in a diagram